# Sort numerically on string 'xx,xx€' in TableSorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am trying to sort the price of my cart items with the tablesorter. Result ascending sort:

```
9,20€   
8,00€   
7,23€   
6,70€   
5,70€   
12,00€  
11,00€
```

My Parser :

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "currency",
    is: function (s) {
        return /^[£$€?.]/.test(s);
    }, format: function (s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[£$€]/g), ""));
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

How can I fix this sort problem?

Comment: As the Euro symbol is at the end of the string you can just use `parseFloat()` without having to use any regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with :

```
 ts.addParser({
            id: "euroValue",
            is: function(s) {
                //u20AC = €
                return /^\d+,\d+\u20AC$/.test(s);
            },
                format: function(s) {
                //replace comma and €-Symbol
                return jQuery.tablesorter.formatInt( s.replace(/[, \u20AC]/g,'') );
            },
            type: "numeric"
});
```